# Model View Controller - what comes under what

Tags: java, model-view-controller

in mvc what comes under what? beans, servlet and DAO. Where these tech will fit in the mvc. what will come under model, view (like jsp,html) and controller

Comment: That's a lot of information. Take each individual concept/module and search for it individually.

Answer (score 1):

Model: Any object that has values that need to be displayed in a view.  These can be domain models, simple pojos, or anything else really.  But typically the objects hold data that needs to be used in the view.

View: The thing that actually displays information to a User.  In your case the JSP/HTML is considered the view.  Note, a User does NOT have to be a human being.

Controller: Used to determine what Model needs to go to which View.  In your case the servlet should be considered the controller.

DAO is actually part of the persistence layer, but generally it is ok for a Controller to access objects in the persistence layer and query them.  You just don't want a controller writing data to a DAO.  That is what services are for.